# How can I add a Google Sitelinks Search Box to my home page?

Tags: cms, search, home

In September [Google announced](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/09/improved-sitelinks-search-box.html) an improved search box within search results for webmasters. Following their guidelines demonstrated in the [Google Developers section](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/richsnippets/sitelinkssearch?utm_source=wmc-blog&utm_medium=direct-referral&utm_campaign=sitelinks-searchbox#examples), they state that you can implement it on your home page either using JSON-LD or Microdata.

I'm trying to implement it using Microdata on my CMS home page, here's the dummy example:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite">
    <meta itemprop="url" content="https://www.example-petstore.com/"/>
    <form itemprop="potentialAction" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SearchAction">
        <meta itemprop="target" content="https://query.example-petstore.com/search?q={search_term_string}"/>
        <input itemprop="query-input" type="text" name="search_term_string" required/>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

If you put this directly into the <kbd>Content</kbd> section of your CMS page, it becomes replaced with:

```
<div><form><input type="text" name="search_term_string" /> <input type="submit" /></form></div>
```

When including it with a template file, like this:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="namespace/sitelinkssearchbox.phtml"}}
```

Where the content of `sitelinkssearchbox.phtml` is:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite">
    <meta itemprop="url" content="http://www.mywebsite.com/"/>
    <form itemprop="potentialAction" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SearchAction">
        <meta itemprop="target" content="http://www.mywebsite.com/catalogsearch/result/?q={search_term_string}"/>
        <input itemprop="query-input" type="text" name="search_term_string" required/>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

When clicking <kbd>Submit</kbd>, I get forwarded to the following URL:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/?search_term_string=4670k
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this the correct behavior - and if so, can I make this div hidden?

Comment: I tried the second method you mentioned (include via template file) and could reproduce this on Magento 1.9.0.1. From what I read on the integration website (https://developers.google.com/webmasters/richsnippets/sitelinkssearch) your adapted code seems correct to me.

Comment: If you find a solution to this, please add it as answer here and accept it by yourself. I guess this will be interesting for further visitors.

Comment: Please log your browser activity - are you sent *directly* to `http://www.mywebsite.com/?search_term_string=4670k` or are you redirected to the root `/` by your server? Also, please verify that the `url` itemprop "[matches] the canonical URL of your domain's homepage."

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you use the microdata option, you are supposed to apply the itemprop, itemscope, etc attributes to your existing search form markup. The reason you see the search button is because you are essentially adding another form to the page. With that in mind you might want to use the json-ld data.

**NB:** I should point out that I've seen both examples of Magento sites without any meta data appearing with sitelink search and sites with meta data that don't display it in the search results. Ultimately there is a google algorithm that determines when to show it.